# Is there a way to compare the current time with a mysql saved time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

So in my php script I compare the current time (date()) with the time from the mysql database but it doesn't work. How do I do this? 
PHP

```
if($row['Datum'] < date(Y-m-d-H-i-s)) { Code to execute}
```

Mysql DATETIME

```
2012-11-13 17:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide the actual code that you are using.

Comment: Could you do the comparison in your SQL query instead? That would be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code has syntax errors, but it's pretty close to something that would work:

```
if ($row['Datum'] < date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
    // Code to execute
}
```

This is likely to be inside a loop, so you should cache the output of `date()`:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// loop here
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['Datum'] < $now) {
        // code to execute
    }
}
```

You could also do the comparison directly in the query:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$db->query("SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE Datum < '$now'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add it into to SQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Datum < now();
```

Comment: This will cause issues if your servers are in another timezone

Answer (score 0):

The mysql date format is

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ( $row['Datum'] < $date) { Code to execute }
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have the format of the date wrong in your php call, a mysql date is in the format `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`. Secondly, you don't need to do this. You can instead use the following:

```
if(strtotime($row['Datum']) < time()) { // Code to execute }
```

This will convert the mysql date to a timestamp, and compare it against the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If your date match the ISO 8601 format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS", you can use the **strtotime** function to convert the string to a Unix timestamp.